# How to get Unicode in Jar

Tags: java, unicode, jar

I called these Strings "మర్డర్,రేప్,తెఫ్ట్, క్రిమినల్ బ్రీచ్ అఫ్ ట్రస్ట్" from a .txt file. When I compiled this in IDE I can able to see these strings. But when I exported it as Jar I am unable to see.

Can any one please tell me how can I get these strings in the out put window when I compiled it in Jar file?

Comment: Asking the same question again doesn't help.

Comment: Where you cannot see in jar? Jar contains classes or source as well?

Comment: No need to ask the same question twice, once is enough.